# Phoenix parsing API paramaters

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to clean up this API endpoint. Is there a way that I can put the params into a model or something?

```
def listen conn, %{"messages" => [%{"body" => body, "chatId" => chatId, "chatType" => chatType, "from" => from, "id" => id, "mention" => mention, "participants" => participants, "readReceiptRequested" => readReceiptRequested, "timestamp" => timestamp, "type" => type}]} do
  sendMessage chatId, from, body
  json conn, 200
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pattern match everything. I would go with:

```
def do_send %{"chatId" => chatId,
              "body" => body,
              "from" => from} = _message,
  do: sendMessage chatId, from, body

def listen conn, %{"messages" => messages} do
  Enum.each(messages, &do_send/1)
  json conn, 200
end
```

---

or, instead, one might do with more erlangish approach:

```
def listen conn, %{"messages" => []} do
  json conn, 200
end

def listen conn, %{"messages" => [message|messages]} do
  with %{"chatId" => chatId,
         "body" => body,
         "from" => from} <- message,
    do: sendMessage chatId, from, body

  listen(conn, %{"messages" => messages})
end
```

Comment: I'm getting "cannot invoke local when/2 inside match, called as: %{"messages" => messages} when :erlang.is_list(messages)" for your first suggestion

Comment: Indeed. Just remove the guard, it is sorta superfluous there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if expecting multiple messages:

```
def listen(conn, %{"messages" => messages}) do
  Enum.each(messages, fn msg ->
    chatId = msg["chatId"]
    from   = msg["from"]
    body   = msg["body"]

    sendMessage(chatId, from, body)
  end)

  conn
  |> put_status(200)
  |> json(%{})
end
```

or for a single message:

```
def listen(conn, %{"messages" => [msg|messages]}) do
  chatId = msg["chatId"]
  from   = msg["from"]
  body   = msg["body"]

  sendMessage(chatId, from, body)

  conn
  |> put_status(200)
  |> json(%{})
end
```